# Can't create SOAP API from WSDL file or URL in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I tried to create a SOAP API from WSDL URL but i got an error because the Publisher can't access the Endpoint of the Backend, only gateway can access the Backend .

[image: Screenshot of WSDL API]

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are creating a pass-through SOAP API, API Manager still needs to access the wsdl at the Control plane. If the URL is not accessible, can you add download it and add it as the file archive?

Comment: same error happens when i tried to add it as WSDL File/Archive

Comment: Try using http:// instead of https://

Answer (score 0):

Publisher should be able to access the wsdl definition through the provided url in order to validate it. Secured urls (exposed through Gateway with security) are not supported in this.

If you check the browser network calls, you might see `Provided URL is not recognized as a WSDL` and there might be errors in the APIM logs indicating that APIM cannot validate provided url. As a workaround you might have to either provide the wsdl url of the backend at this step directly or use the file/archive option.

Comment: In a distributed deployment of WSO2 there is no open flow between the API Publisher and the backend .The only open flow is between Gateway and Endpoint .So i have to open a flow between the publisher and Endpoint !! because i got same error when i tried to add it as WSDL File/Archive.

Comment: Were you able to check the network tab in the browser? it might show if you have any validation issues in this step